# Возможно ли программно сменить текущее устройство воспроизведения звука

Tags: c++, windows

Язык не принципиален, но хотелось бы на C++. Суть задачи: указать 2 устройства воспроизведения звука. При запуске меняем с первого на второе и закрываем.

По сути нужно выяснить какое устройство активно на данный момент и сделать активным второе устройство. Приветствуется пример кода. Если нет, то хотя бы направление куда копать?

Comment: Язык-то, может, и не принципиален, а вот ОС - вполне. Винда судя по тэгам?

Comment: Посмотри тут: http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-05/programmatically-or-command-line-change-the-default-sound-playback-device-in-windows-7/

Comment: И тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054371/programmatically-switch-audio-devices-on-windows-7

Comment: Устройство воспроизведения чего?

Comment: Устройство воспроизведения звука. Прошу прощения, что не уточнил.

Comment: копайте в сторону Endpoint API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370793(v=vs.85).aspx